# function to get enddate from startdate & duration in openerp

Tags: odoo

this is the first code
class timetable_timetable(osv.osv):
         _name='timetable.timetable'
         _columns={
                      'name': fields.char('Name',size="64",required=True),
                      'course': fields.many2one('college.course','Course'),
                      'semester': fields.many2one('course.semester','Semester'),
                      'subject' : fields.one2many('timetable.subjects','timetable_id','Subject')
            }
timetable_timetable()

this is the second code
class timetable_subjects(osv.osv):
       _name = 'timetable.subjects'
       _columns ={
                      'timetable_id' : fields.many2one('timetable.timetable','Time Table'),
                      'subject_id': fields.many2one('semester.subject','Subject'),
                      'start_date': fields.datetime('Start Date',store=True),
                      'duration' : fields.float('Duration',size=64,required=True),
                      'end_date' : fields.datetime('End Date',store=True),
                      'professor' : fields.many2one('professor.professor','Professor')
                      }
timetable_subjects()

i want to make a function on_change which returns me end_date from start_date & duration. So how can i make that function.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your `onchange` method for **end_date**,

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def my_onchange(self, cr, uid, ids, s_date, duration):
    return {'value': {'end_date': (datetime.strptime(s_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + relativedelta(days=duration)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}}
```

If your duration is in terms of months or years, write `relativedelta(months=duration)` for months and `relativedelta(years=duration)` for years and same way for **hours or minutes or seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

def on_change(self, cr, uid, ids, t_date, duration):

```
    res = {'end_date': False}
    if t_date:
        now = datetime.strptime(t_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        e_date = now + timedelta(hours=duration)
        print e_date
        f_date = datetime.strftime(e_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        res['end_date'] = f_date
    return {'value': res}
```